# How to open a UDP port?

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, port

I have an assignment that I need to write a program that opens a port in the network, than I should check if the port is opened in another machine using nmap or netcat.

Well, I already did that.. but I did it using socket, I created a socket then binded and keep listening, that's the only way I know to do it. is there a better way ? because my way doesn't seem write.. 
Also, is opening a port for TCP is different then a port for UDP ?

Note: I'm trying to figure out how to write a program that open a port in C/C++, but Python or Java are fine too..

Edit: I'm fine with TCP, but still didn't figure out how to open a port for UDP. Since there's no "listen" in UDP, how am I supposed to keep the port open ? I wrote a program that creates a socket for UDP and binds it, but when I scan it with nmap, it says "open/filtered", how am I supposed to make it only Open ?

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to edit the meaning of a question after you originally ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way to "open" a port.

A port is called "open" if something is listening on it. So, by definition, you need to listen on a port for it to become open.

Comment: Well, that works with TCP, but with UDP there's no "listen". So I tried both sending and receiving, nmap says it's open/filtered. From what I read about ports, filtered <> open. Or it's always Filtered for UDP ?

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy With UDP, you listen for datagrams just by binding a socket to that port. Not sure whether scanning tools can detect open UDP ports or not.